# Google MAP by Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to Google map API.

when I run my Emulator it is show this:

[image]

what i can do??

Comment: you completely changed the question. You should not do that coz the answer i posted answered your question before the edit. But now your question and my answer do not relate at all.

Answer (score 2):

To the edited Question

Google maps require google play services installed.

You cannot runs maps on Emulator because emulator do not have google play services apk installed.

Quoting docs

> If you want to test your app on the emulator, expand the directory for
>   Android 4.2.2 (API 17) or a higher version, select Google APIs, and
>   install it. Then create a new AVD with Google APIs as the platform
>   target.

**You require emulator of Andorid 4.2.2 or higher with google api's as the platform**

**Note :The below answer is to the question before the Edit. OP changed
the question completely.**

You are missing a meta tag in your manifest file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
...// rest of the code
```

Also you have

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
```

So you should be using `SupportMapFragment` instead of `MapFragment`.

So change this

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

to

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

Also extend `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`.

You can also get rid of the below. Not required

```
<permission 
    android:name="com.mapee.googlemapapi.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.mapee.googlemapapi.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: @AndyError it din't work does not help. Any errors. What does the stacktrace say after the update. Post the same. The changes are necessary

Comment: how do use this i can not understand....    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

to

android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

Comment: @AndyError for api level 11 and below you need to used support based fragments. So you will be using `SupportMapFragment`. How to use jut replace `MapFragment` with `SupportMapFragment`.

Comment: i change this   <activity> ??

Comment: @AndyError it has nothing to do with  `<activity>` and i never mentioned about the same

Comment: bro i when i use supportMapFragmet then i also crashed

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mapee.googlemapapi/com.mapee.googlemapapi.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mapee.googlemapapi.MainActivity cannot be cast to

Comment: @AndyError looks like wrong import. post the full stacktrace and the activity code along with import statements. If you do it wrong it will crash

Comment: @AndyError are you going to post your activity code and the new stacktrace??

Comment: if i use this where my code? <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"  />

Comment: @AndyError did you even read my post. i have showed the same. I can't post the entire code and i will not. If you want further help post your code or forget help. good luck